# Having selected items from listview, delete objects in list<>

Tags: c#, windows

This is mostly for my curiosity because I couldn't find anything that suited my question.

I made a `List<T>` and used it's contents to show them in a Listview.

Later I tried deleting them from the Listview and it worked fine, but whenever I re-added an item (through the windows app) the `List<T>` contents came back up, which clearly means that I had to remove the items from the `List<T>`.

I tried many index methods , but nothing seemed to work. I'm trying to find a way to connect the selected items being "deleted" on ListView to the actual content on the list<> so i can then remove it.

Can anyone help out?

Comment: well how  about showing your code.. that would be a good place to start  are you removing it from the ListView.. or the List<T> object itself.. are you trying to rebind the List<T> to the ListView..? showing code will help shorten the numerous questions many may have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It mostly depends on the relation between your listview and your list.

What is probably happening here is that the listview is only a display of the list you have. When you delete stuff from the view, the underlying list is not updated. Try deleting directly from the list instead

If you're using ListViewItem you can store the item in the .Tag property and search for it in your List when you are deleting

Comment: this is exactly what I meant! Could you please show me a code example of searching through the .Tag property ?
- The problem is, I can't delete directly from list<> cause things are chosen from the app directly, like it's not up to me

Comment: There are other controls in winforms such as the datagridview which allows you to bind a source to the control. Those may be better suited to your needs